# ViewEncapsulation is not transferring from server to browser when using withServerTransition in Angular Universal SSR

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal

I have an angular universal web app, where I am trying to implement transfer state.
To do so I am adding `BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: environment.appId })` to my `AppModule`, however it is producing an unintended consequence.

When the application bootstraps it damages the css, which I am attempting to fix by adding new ViewEncapsulation to certain components.

There are no Errors being log in the server.

I am also able to see that when the transition happens it changes an html elements in component elements for example:

From server:

```html
<header-nav-bar _nghost-yna-c97> ... </header-nav-bar>
```

to browser:

```html
<header-nav-bar _nghost-com.myAppName.appAv-c97> ... </header-nav-bar>
```

Moreover, I am having issues with TransferState where I only am able to get the transfer state for i18n. More information on that issue can be found at: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72448274/angular-ssr-transferstate-getkey-null-returns-null-while-i-can-see-objets-if)

EDIT: appId was the issue my app Id included dots and that damaged the `ng-transfer` or simply the css.